# Vue.js - How to print in html page a string variable (returned from a filter) that contains break line

Tags: javascript, html, string, vue.js, filter

I'm quite new in vue.js and I'm trying to realize a simple code that prints in a html page a string (returned from a filter) that contains break lines. I already tryed to use both \n and &#13&#10 for the generation of the string but it doesn't work, so the browser print in the same row the content of the string.

This is the filter in vue.js

```
 myFilter (withBreakLine){

 let string_array = ['Hi', 'my', 'friend'];
 let Result;

 if (withBreakLine) {

   for (let i = 0; i <= string_array.legth-1; i++) {
       Result = Result + '\n' + string_array[i];
   }

 } else {

   for (let i = 0; i <= string_array.legth-1; i++) {
       Result = Result + ' ' + string_array[i];
   }

 }

 return Result;

}
```

In HTML, with this code:

```
<span>{{0 | myFilter }} </span>
```

I expect:

```
Hi my friend
```

Instead, with this code:

```
<span>{{1 | myFilter }} </span>
```

I expect:

```
Hi 
my 
friend
```

How can I solve?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could add a `<br>` tag between the words. Or put all the words in different divs instead of one span. Or use a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without resorting to the *terrible* `v-html`, you can instead just apply the `white-space: pre-wrap` style to the span.

```vue
<span style="white-space: pre-wrap">{{ 1 | myFilter }}</span>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on _terrible_ `v-html`? I'm kinda new to Vue and do not understand why it should be considered bad.

Comment: It's a security vulnerability because it allows for [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Comment: Just tried, the break lines now correctly works, but I noticed that it prints the fist row with a TAB, like beginning tabulation of the paragraph. Solved with style="white-sapce: pre-line"

Comment: @FLFDA That shouldn't be the case unless the string you're rendering begins with whitespace. Are you sure you didn't split the `<span>` and `{{ }}` onto separate lines, which can also cause this?

Comment: You're right, I put them onto separates lines. In the same row it works. Problem solved, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `<pre>` tag for that.

For instance, when you have a string `str` equals to `something \n new line` you can write

```html
<pre>{{ str }}</pre>
```

And, as expected, you'll get

```
something
 new line
```